# how insert an index into an array in a loop js

Tags: javascript

I want to make two tables to identify the position of each image before an animation.
I tried several solutions I think the most logical would be a .push() but it doesn't work.
Here is a code snippet:

```js
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass img')
let fromRight = []
let fromLeft = []
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  document.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    if (img[i].getBoundingClientRect().x < (window.scrollY/2)) {
      fromLeft.push(i)
    } 
    else if (img[i].getBoundingClientRect().x > (window.scrollY/2)) {
      fromRight.push(i)
    }
  })
  console.log('left :', fromLeft);
  console.log('right :', fromRight);
}
```

I also tried:

```js
Array.prototype.push.apply(fromLeft, i)
```

And :

```js
fromLeft.concat(i)
```

Please I need help!

Comment: You might want to clone the array and push into the new one instead. Pushing inside the loop changes the length so the loop probably doesn't loop how you would expect.

Comment: @youdateme But they are not `push`ing into the array they are looping on. Besides, the `push` is happening in a callback, so is most likely not occurring until a later time.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('load', ()=>{` Should that be `img[i].addEventListener('load', ()=>{` ??

Comment: You're adding a new independent "load" listener to the document for each image.  Either that whole block should be wrapped in a single listener, or remove the listeners entirely, but definitely don't add a document listener for each image.

Comment: @James I also tried

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the whole code inside a single listener

```js
document.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
  const img = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass img')
  let fromRight = []
  let fromLeft = []
  for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    if (img[i].getBoundingClientRect().x < (window.scrollY/2)) {
      fromLeft.push(i)
    } 
    else if (img[i].getBoundingClientRect().x > (window.scrollY/2)) {
      fromRight.push(i)
    }
  }
  console.log('left :', fromLeft);
  console.log('right :', fromRight);
})
```

Comment: thanks but is not working, the response in the concole is : main.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: fromLeft is not defined

Comment: Doesn't make sense since it's defined in that very function.  Check for typos.

Comment: yes I have no more error message indeed thank you

Comment: the only problem is that now only the last array gets filled with all the values

Comment: Perhaps you meant window.innerWidth / 2 instead of window.scrollY / 2?  Not really sure.

Comment: you are the best a big thank you it was my mistake from the beginning